# Помогите написать правильно скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть.форма,сначала выпадающий список(юр лица,физ лица)в зависимости от выбора, ниже появляются соответствующие выбору поля(физ.л.-снилс,юр.л.-инн,огрн)буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как самое простое решение в лоб:

```js
function Selected(a) {
  var label = a.value;
  if (label == 1) {
    document.getElementById("Label1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("Label2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Label3").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (label == 2) {
    document.getElementById("Label1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Label2").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("Label3").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Label1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Label2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Label3").style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Dest" aria-required="true" onChange="Selected(this)">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">-</option>
  <option value="1">Физические лица</option>
  <option value="2">Юридические лица</option>
</select>
<input id="Label1" type="text" placeholder="СНИЛС" style='display: none;'>
<input id="Label2" type="text" placeholder="ИНН" style='display: none;'>
<input id="Label3" type="text" placeholder="ОГРН" style='display: none;'>
```